# How to Iterate through the Android ArrayList and get the Index

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have this two `ArrayLists`. I need to iterate through the `stationNames` Array and get the index. Then return the value of the same index of `stationIDs` array. How do i achieve this? Please help me. The existing solutions on stackoverflow didn't  work on this. I am new to android development.

When i iterate through the Array like the following code it give an error saying `Array type expected; found: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>`

```
ArrayList<String> stationNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> stationIDs = new ArrayList<String>();

stationName = "Hello"

int index = -1;
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < stationNames.length; i++) {
        if (stationNames[i].equals(stationName)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.d("Excetion!",e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
return stationIDs[index];
```

Comment: Consider creating a map from station name -> station id, then each lookup will be O(1) instead of O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without all the hazzle of try catches and for loops. I could do the same task with one line of code, like following...

```
int output = stationIDs.get(stationNames.indexOf(stationName));
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3):

stationNames here is not an array , but an `ArrayList`. So, you cannot use `.length` on it, use `.size()` :

Even simpler to do :

```
return stationNames.indexOf(stationName);
```

if it is found in the list will return its position or -1 if not.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `indexOf` method of the `ArrayList` object.

```
ArrayList<String> stationNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> stationIDs = new ArrayList<String>();

String stationName = "Hello"

int index = stationNames. indexOf(stationName);

if(index!=-1){
 String value= stationIDs[index];
}
```